# How to implement a counter using a lambda?

Tags: python, if-statement, lambda, counter

Can I implement a counter using a `lambda` function in python or some expression more pythonic?

Here is my code:

```
counter = 0     
if 0 < arrival_time:
   counter += 1
else:
   pass
```

this is what I tried:

```
count_late = lambda x, arrival_time: x+=1 if 0 < arrival_time else pass
counter_late(counter, arrival_time)
```

The error:
[image]

What am I missing or how can I improve this code?

Comment: One last thing: When people talk about "a counter using a function", they're often Lisp types looking for something like [this code](https://repl.it/repls/GroundedFearfulInstance). But if that's what you were aiming for, see the second version directly below it for a more Pythonic solution. (Instances and closures are dual, but that doesn't mean there's no reason to ever prefer one over the other—it's almost always more readable one way or the other.)

Comment: Just a small improvement I suggest for your code: you don't need an `else` statement for every `if` statement. Removing the `else: pass` won't affect how your code runs. It saves space and, on some occasions, headaches.

Comment: @abarnert and is it better to use a class when I am dealing with counters? or just initiate a variable counter and the loop? thanks for the code

Comment: @may It depends entirely on what you're doing. If you want a counter that encapsulates some state and provides opaque methods to updaet it, like the example I gave in the link above, then you want a class. If you just want to keep adding to an int, then you probably want either a pure function that returns a new value, or a function that updates a global variable; no need for a class either way. Without seeing the rest of your design, it's hard to say which one you want.

Comment: Any particular reason you want to do it with a `lambda`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both `x+=1` and `pass` are statements, but `lambda` is an expression, and you can't put statements inside an expression.

But that's fine.

`lambda` and `def` both just create a function, in the same way, but `lambda` is more limited.

If you need to create a function in the middle of an expression, you have to use `lambda`—but that's not the case here, since you're creating it just to use in an assignment statement.

If there's no good name for a function, you may want to use `lambda`, but that's not the case here either, because you're immediately giving it a name.

Some people (mostly those who've spent too much time with Lisp- or ML-family functional languages) also like to use `lambda` to make it clear that they're writing a "pure function", one that has no side effects and returns a value that depends only on the value of its parameters. But that's not the case here either. (If you changed it to `lambda x, arrival_time: x+1 if 0 < arrival_time else x`, that would be a good example of a pure function. You'd then call it with, e.g., `x = count_late(x)`.)

So, there's absolutely no reason to use `lambda` here in the first place. Just use `def`:

```
def count_late(x, arrival_time):
    if 0 < arrival_time:
        x += 1
```

---

However, it's worth noting that, while this is now valid syntax, it isn't going to do any good.

Numbers are immutable; there's no way to change the number `2` into the number `3`, because that would break all of physics. When you write `x += 1`, that just makes the local variable `x` into a name for the number `3` instead of a name for the number `2`. If you call it with `count_late(spam, 5)` it's not going to change what `spam` means, just as if you call it with `count_late(2*3, 5)` it's not going to change what `2*3` means.

So, you probably wanted to:

- Make this a pure function that `return`s a value (as mentioned above, this would mean you *could* use `lambda`, and some people would be happy with that, but I'd still definitely prefer `def` here), or
- Make it a method of some object that has a `self.x`, or
- Make `x` a global.

Comment: thanks for the explanation as I am a newbie in python, I found it hard to improve the code with less code using python's features. I believe your explanation will be a reference for me, thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: "one is a statement, the other is an expression. statements don't go in expressions" that is called a bug

Answer (score 2):

if you have a function counter_late() :

```
**
#the 'counter' is in counter_late() or  global
counter_late((lambda arrival_time: counter+1 if 0 < arrival_time else PASS), 10)
```

**

else :

```
**
counter = 0 #global variable

counter = (lambda arrival_time: counter+1 if 0 < arrival_time else PASS)(10)

#check the value of counter 
print('conter=',counter)
**
```

10 is a variable what you want for a value of arrival_time.

if you get a syntax err.

PASS is change other value,  you want to a number or condition.

for eg)

counter = (lambda arrival_time: counter+1 if 0 < arrival_time else 1)(0)

Comment: this is also an interesting way to see lambda function. The other answer was more aligned but I thank you for sharing this knowledge with me

Comment: What is `PASS` supposed to be here? As written it just turns the `SyntaxError` into a `NameError`. The only value I can think of that really makes sense is `counter`, but just doing `PASS = counter` isn't going to help anything, because after the first time you do `counter = …`, that updates `counter` to the new value but leaves `PASS` as the old one.

Comment: You're right. I miss that and modified.
PASS was used in the needs of the questioner.