# Lambda How to return count+=1 Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I want to apply lambda function on my dataset but it's not returning a count value. If the `x` is higher than 5, `count = count +1` and it should be return the count:

[image]

```
b = a.apply(lambda x, count=0: count=count+1 if x==5)
b
```

Comment: So do you want to just calculate number of rows with `x > 5`?

Comment: `a['a'].eq(5).sum()` or `a['a'].count(5)`?

Comment: [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51145212/7937057) The solution you are looking for is here.

[reason](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51145121/7937057) and the reason why you shouldn't use this solution in this case.

Comment: `lambda` bodies are expressions, not statements.  You could use a named function instead of a lambda (or the new "walrus operator" `:=`), but in either case, it still wouldn't do what you want since `count` is local to the function (lambda or otherwise), so its value is lost when the function returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check Below code based on your statement **x is higher than 5**:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4,5,6,1,7,3,8,2]})

df.assign(flag = np.where(df['a']>5,1,0)).\
assign(count=lambda x: x.flag.cumsum())[['a','count']]
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have several options to count elements in a list that fit into a condition, like:

```py
countCondition = len(list(filter(lambda x: x == 5, a)))
```

or

```py
countCondition = len([x for x in a if x == 5])
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':range(10)})
df.apply(lambda x: [x+1 if x >= 5 else x for x in df.a])
```

Output:

```
   a
0  0
1  1
2  2
3  3
4  4
5  5
6  6
7  7
8  8
9  9
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call a function that does the comparison and returns the value, e.g.:

```
a = {'a': [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 6]}
a = pd.DataFrame(a)

count = 0
def count_x(x):
    if x > 5:
        global count
        count += 1

    return count

b = a['a'].apply(lambda x: count_x(x))
```

note that `global count` to prevent passing `count` as parameter.

`print(b)` gives:

```
0    0
1    0
2    0
3    0
4    1
5    2
```